# What's the possible usage of glFramebufferRenderbuffer under GLES2?

Tags: opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I'm trying to get my opengl framework to run on a raspberry pi 3, using GLES2.
On the core profile, I do this:

```
    glGenRenderbuffers ( 1, &ColorBufferGLID );
    glBindRenderbuffer ( GL_RENDERBUFFER, ColorBufferGLID );
    glRenderbufferStorage ( GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_RGBA, Dimensions.x, Dimensions.y );
    glFramebufferRenderbuffer ( GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_RENDERBUFFER, ColorBufferGLID );

    glGenRenderbuffers ( 1, &DepthBufferGLID );
    glBindRenderbuffer ( GL_RENDERBUFFER, DepthBufferGLID );
    glRenderbufferStorage ( GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT32F, Dimensions.x, Dimensions.y );
    glFramebufferRenderbuffer ( GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, GL_RENDERBUFFER, DepthBufferGLID );

    glBindFramebuffer (  GL_READ_FRAMEBUFFER, OpenGLID );
    glBindFramebuffer ( GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER, 0 );
    glBlitFramebuffer ( In_LowerLeft.x, In_LowerLeft.y, In_UpperRight.x, In_UpperRight.y,
                    In_LowerLeft.x, In_LowerLeft.y, In_UpperRight.x, In_UpperRight.y,
                    GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT,
                    GL_NEAREST );
```

And under GLES2, I do the same, but with different enums, but later on, there is no glBlitFramebuffer, so I cannot display it.
I know I can do the same with a texture instead of a renderbuffer, using glFramebufferTexture2D, but then I'd have to draw a screen-sized quad just to show it.

If I cannot blit or read from the render buffer, what's the point of it? How can it be used? How else can I adapt this piece of code to GLES2?

Answer (score 0):

As noted by the documentation for [Renderbuffer Objects](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Renderbuffer_Object) on the OpenGL Wiki,

> the only way to use a renderbuffer object is to attach it to a
>   Framebuffer Object. After you bind that FBO to the context, and set up
>   the draw or read buffers appropriately, you can use pixel transfer
>   operations to read and write to it.

So, you can use pixel transfer operations to read/write to/from it (eg. [`glReadPixels`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/es3.0/html/glReadPixels.xhtml)/[`glDrawPixels`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glDrawPixels.xml)). It's also useful if you don't need direct access to the buffer, but require it for rendering. For example, a depth buffer, used to render an offscreen target, but which is never directly sampled itself.

To your question of how to port the code - [`glBlitFramebuffer`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/es3.0/html/glBlitFramebuffer.xhtml) is available in OpenGL ES 3.0. If you must target OpenGL 2.0, your suggestion of drawing a screen-sized quad is a reasonable solution. Although possible, I would not suggest using `glReadPixels` and `glDrawPixels`, as this requires all data be downloaded into system memory, which will be very slow.